# mysql can't specify target table with select and subselect and select

Tags: mysql, sql-update

I have this query:

```
UPDATE answers AS aa SET aa.question_id=(SELECT q.id FROM question AS q WHERE q.question LIKE (SELECT a.question_prev FROM answers AS a))
```

Error:

> mysql cant specify target table

And can't figure out how to edit it to work

Answer (score 1):

try this,

```
UPDATE  answers a
        INNER JOIN question b
            ON b.question = a.question_prev
SET     a.question_id = b.id
```

*Please do backup first before executing the statement.*

Comment: hm... thx for soon answer.. i cant delete this post but i figure it out other way.. i have third select not needed.